# Efficient byte-wise rotation within 32-bit words in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-manipulation

Let's say we've a 32-bit register which is composed of four bytes `R = b0|b1|b2|b3`.

What I'd like to do is to compute `R'` such that`R' = (b0 <<< x) | (b1 <<< x) | (b2 <<< x) | (b3 <<< x)` where `x` refers to an arbitrary value and `<<<` refers to left byte-wise rotation (i.e. `10101110 <<< 2 = 10111010`).

What is the most efficient way to do that in ARM assembly?

Comment: Do you want ARM or thumb assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines:
(source value in R0, result in R0)

```
LDR R1,=0xC0C0C0C0  @ mask for 2 MS bits of each byte (pseudo-instruction) 
LDR R2,=0xFCFCFCFC  @ negative mask for 2 LS bits of each byte (pseudo-instruction) 
AND R1,R1,R0        @ R1 holds the values of 2 MS bits of each byte of R0  
MOV R0,R0,LSL #2    @ Shift R0 by 2 bits to the left (2 MS bits are discarded)  
AND R0,R0,R2        @ Zero out 2 LS bits of each byte
ORR R0,R0,R1,LSR #6 @ Move the 'extracted' 2 MS bits of each byte to destination
```

Used the LDR '=' [pseudo-instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Babbfdih.html) because I'm lazy, there probably exists a more optimal way to generate these masks...

**Edit** 
*(Cheers to @PeterCordes)*

Yes, one of the shifts can be embedded into AND, we can also change the order of operations slightly and use a different mask but the result will be about the same anyway.

In 'C' this would look something like this:

```
unsigned byte_rot2l(unsigned x) {
    unsigned result;
    result = ((x<<2) & 0xfcfcfcfc);
    result |= ((x>>6) & 0x03030303);
    return (result);
}
```

In ARM 32 this can be expressed as:

```
LDR R2,=0xFCFCFCFC   @ mask for 6 MS bits of each byte (pseudo-instruction) 
LDR R1,=0x03030303   @ mask for 2 LS bits of each byte (pseudo-instruction) 
AND R2,R2,R0,LSL #2  @ R2 := R0 shifted left by 2 bits, zero out the 2 LS bits of each byte (R0 remains unchanged)
AND R0,R1,R0,LSR #6  @ R0 := R0 shifted right by 6 bits, zero out all but the 2 LS bits of each byte
ORR R0,R0,R2         @ "Combine" the bits together
MOV PC,LR            @ Return result in R0
```

**Edit #2**
The second line, which translates by the assembler into a PC-relative Load of a 32-bit constant from a literal pool, can be replaced with:

```
MVN R1,R2
```

Thus eliminating the need in storing 0x03030303 in the literal pool. However, I'm struggling to understand why gcc on Godbolt does not use this optimisation, no matter what compiler options I try. Has anyone got an idea?

Comment: Does 32-bit ARM have repeating-bit-pattern immediates like AArch64?  I think AArch64 could use masks as immediates for AND.  Anyway, if you're going to load 2 constant masks, you can fold a shift into one of the ANDs, right?  like `and r0, r2, lsl #2`

Comment: @PeterCordes ARM has them, but only in thumb mode.  IIRC they always cause a 4 byte instruction to be generated.  I thought about going for thumb code as well, but it didn't turn out to be any better, so I went with ARM code for better clarity.

Comment: @fuz I edited the answer yet again and I raised a question there...

Comment: @tum_ I think neither compiler has this sort of optimisation implemented.  Perhaps you could try raising an enhancement request on the respective bug trackers.

Answer (score 4):

We can get the desired effect by implementing the rotation by means of shifts and masking out the bits we don't want.  This gives us something like this code in C:

```
/* byte-wise right rotate */
unsigned brrot(unsigned R, x)
{
    unsigned mask;

    mask = 0x01010100U - (0x01010101U << R);

    return ((x & mask) >> R | (x & ~mask) << (8-R));
}
```

Translated to ARM thumb assembly, this should give us:

```
ldr r2, =0x01010101      @ load 0x01010101
sub r3, r2, #1           @ compute 0x01010100
sub r2, r2, r3, lsl r0   @ compute mask
and r3, r1, r2           @ compute x & mask
bic r2, r1, r2           @ compute x & ~mask
lsr r3, r3, r0           @ compute (x & mask) >> R
rsb r0, r0, #8           @ compute 8 - R
orr r0, r3, r2, lsl r0   @ compute (x & mask) >> R | (x & ~mask) << (8 - R)
```

If the carry flag is known to be clear before this sequence, you can save one instruction by replacing the two subtractions with

```
sbc r2, r2, r3, lsl r0   @ compute mask
```

Comment: Can you fold the `lsr` into another instruction, like `and`?  Probably not without a shifted mask, so only viable for a compile-time-constant rotate.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not really, I thought about this as well.

Comment: Out of interest, do you often program in C89 or some old C compiler? Because lately I rarely see unassigned variables being declared at the top of the function (i.e. I would expect `const unsigned mask = 0x0101...`).

Comment: I consider it cleaner to first declare all variables.  Initialisers with variable values are not supported by some compilers (like Open Watcom), so I try to avoid them.

Comment: Shouldn't one of the shifts be by 8-R?